# In Extjs get textfield value which is inside the custom fieldcontainer

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1 and have created a custom fieldcontainer with xtype:ptextfield, it is created by extending a "FieldContainer" which has items img and textfield and what i want is to access the **textfield value** from **ptextfield** which is **fieldcontainer**.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.define('PTextField', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
        alias: 'widget.ptextfield',
        requires: ['Ext.form.TextField', 'Ext.Component'],
        alias: 'widget.ptextfield',
        height: 20,
        width: 170,
        fieldLabel: 'A',
        labelAlign: 'top',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        BLANK_IMAGE_URL: '',

        initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;
            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'component',
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                    autoEl: {
                        tag: 'img',
                        src: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    itemId: 'textid',
                    width: 100
                }]
            });
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Hello',
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        //layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'ptextfield',
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            id: 'pcontainer1',
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property
                    fn: function () {
                        var me = this;
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                            waitMsg: 'Saving changes...',
                            url: '/Home/SaveChanges',
                            jsonData: {
                                id: this.id,
                                value: this.down('#textid').getRawValue()
                            },
                            failure: function (response, options) {
                                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Warning', 'Oops...');
                            },
                            success: function (response, options) {
                                var text = response.responseText;
                                // process server response here
                                console.log('Changes saved successfully.');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'ptextfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
            id: 'pcontainer2'
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

In the below line i am getting "ptextfield" fieldcontainer in "this" and "this.id" is giving me "pcontainer1"
but i am not able to figure out how to get the "value" of textfield which is sitting inside the "ptextfield" fieldcontainer.

I am getting error at the below line:
jsonData: { id: this.id, value: this.down('#textid').getRawValue() }

Error is - this.down('#textid') is null (firebug)
(chrome)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getRawValue' of null 
Ext.create.items.listeners.change.fn 
(anonymous function) 
Ext.apply.createListenerWrap.wrap

where `"this.down(#textid').getRawValue()"` should give me `textfield value`, which i am not getting i am not able to traverse.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you listening to the change event of the container's html element? and not say the text field?

this way is probably simpler for ya:

put this on the ptextfield:

```
listeners: {
                render: function(component) {
                    component.down('textfield').on('change', function() {
                        console.log(this, arguments);
                        // "this" is the textfield
                        // do your ajax here
                    });
                }

            }
```